# SharePoint CU installation - Updating from Aug 2013 to May 2016 CU

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update, patching

I am working in an environment where the sharepoint patches are in the below level.

**SP2013**:

1. Farm 1 - Build Version 15.0.4727.1000 - June 9th, 2015
2. Farm 2 - Build Version 15.0.4535.1000 - ​August 2013 CU.

**SP2010**:

1. Farm 3 - Build Version 14.0.7105.5000 - MS13-067 (Security) Aug 2013
2. Farm 4 - Build Version 14.0.6029.1000 - SP2010 Service Pack1.

Now I need to install the recent updates on each farm as per MS recommendation for better performance of the servers. As the patch levels are very old, I am confused on planning the patch installation. Can i install the recent update directly or do I need to install any specific updates first and then install the recent CU? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to apply Service Pack 1 to SharePoint 2013 prior to updating to May 2016 CU. For SharePoint 2010, you will need to apply Service Pack 2 prior to updating to the May 2016 CU.

Answer (score 2):

all Updates for SharePoint 2013 require SharePoint Server 2013 SP1 to be installed first.Read More here: [May 2016 CU for SharePoint 2013 product family is available for download](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/05/11/may-2016-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-product-family-is-available-for-download/)

It is required to have SP2 installed for the base product and all installed language packs to install May 2016 CU for SharePoint 2010. Read more here [May 2016 CU for SharePoint 2010 product family is available for download](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/05/11/may-2016-cu-for-sharepoint-2010-product-family-is-available-for-download/)