# Does a SharePoint CU contain earlier CU's?

Tags: cumulative-update

Does the latest CU for SharePoint include all the CU's up to that date?

I am having problems downloading the earlier CU's on Microsoft site and wondering if downloading SP1 + latest CU would be enough to install an up to date environment.

Thanks,
Ova

Comment: FAQ, It does, SP1 + latest CU is enough for SP 2013...http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/185249/sharepoint-cu-installation-updating-from-aug-2013-to-may-2016-cu

Comment: what is your sharepoint version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sharepoint 2013.

- SharePoint Server 2013 SP1 + latest CU. (Previous releases of the SharePoint Server 2013 cumulative update included both the executable and the .CAB file in the same [self-extracting executable download](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/10/11/october-2016-cu-for-sharepoint-2013-product-family-is-available-for-download/))

For SharePoint 2010

- SP2 installed before installing the CU + Latest CU( This CU includes all SharePoint 2010 fixes (including all SharePoint 2010 security fixes) [released since SP2](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2016/10/11/october-2016-cu-for-sharepoint-2010-product-family-is-available-for-download/))

For SharePoint 2016

- RTM + latest CU

Comment: For SharePoint 2007, CUs do *not* contain previous CUs